# Numbering all environments within chapter with the same counter?

Tags: numbering, environments, counters

I want to number my definitions, lemmas, examples, etc. as "chapter"."number of environments"... For example:

```
1. Chapter One
        1.1 Env. A
    1.2 Section One
        1.2 Env. B
        1.3 Env. A
    1.3 Section Two
        1.4 Env. C
        1.5 Env. B
```

But at the moment I am only able to get

```
1. Chapter One
        1.1 Env. A
    1.2 Section One
        1.1 Env. B
        1.2 Env. A
    1.3 Section Two
        1.1 Env. C
        1.2 Env. B
...
```

I know that I can use

```
\newtheorem{A}{A}[chapter]
\newtheorem{B}[A]{B}
```

if I want that B has the same counter as A, but this way only works if I start all my chapters with the same enviroment...

Is there a simple way so that ALL enviroments share the same counter within a chapter?

Sorry for the bad format, but I hope you still get my problem!

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/259038/134144

Comment: Ah, thanks, you're right! Since every section in my work contains at least one theorem enviroment, I can set the counter of the others to the theorem-counter, sure! Thank you!